# Xamarin android renderer: button is round the first time, but when pressed on the backbutton it becomes square

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, renderer

I have made a renderer to make a round button in Android. It gets executed with no problem when you enter the page normally. But when you press the backbutton to go back to that page the button becomes a square.

My renderer code:

```cs
public class FloatingActionButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
{
    private GradientDrawable _normal, _pressed;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var button = (FloatingActionButton)e.NewElement;

            button.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;

        }
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object s, EventArgs e) {
        var button = (FloatingActionButton)s;
        var radius = (float)Math.Min(button.Width, button.Height) * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

        // Create a drawable for the button's normal state
        _normal = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();

        if (button.BackgroundColor.R == -1.0 && button.BackgroundColor.G == -1.0 && button.BackgroundColor.B == -1.0)
            _normal.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff2c2e2f"));
        else
            _normal.SetColor(button.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());

        _normal.SetCornerRadius(radius);

        // Create a drawable for the button's pressed state
        _pressed = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();
        var highlight = Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorActivatedHighlight }).GetColor(0, Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
        _pressed.SetColor(highlight);
        _pressed.SetCornerRadius(radius);

        // Add the drawables to a state list and assign the state list to the button
        var sld = new StateListDrawable();
        sld.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, _pressed);
        sld.AddState(new int[] { }, _normal);
        Control.SetBackground(sld);
        button.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
    }
}
```

So I create a handler for size changed. It gets created with no problem both times but it only enters the event when you enter the page normally. It doesn't enter when you press the backbutton.

Screenshots of the floating action button:
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m17Dz.png)

**Edit**
Some extra information:
I forgot to mention that I override the `OnBackButtonPressed` of my `MasterDetailPage`, I did this because otherwise it was crashing when I pressed on the backbutton:

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{

    Page page = GoPrevPage();
    if (page.GetType() == typeof(LoginPage))
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }

    else
    {
        page.Parent = null;
        Detail = page;

        navigationDrawerList.SelectedItem = selectedMenuItems.LastOrDefault();

    }
    return true;
}
```

The GoPrevPage is a function coming for a static class:

```cs
public static class BackButtonHelper
{
    public static List<Page> prevPages;
    public static List<MasterPageItem> selectedMenuItems;

    static BackButtonHelper() {
        prevPages = new List<Page>();
        selectedMenuItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();
    }

    public static Page GoPrevPage() {
        prevPages.RemoveAt(prevPages.Count - 1);
        selectedMenuItems.RemoveAt(selectedMenuItems.Count - 1);
        return prevPages[prevPages.Count - 1]; 
    }
    public static void AddPageToPrev(Page page, MasterPageItem masterPageItem)
    {

        if (!IsToegevoegd(page.ClassId))
        {
            prevPages.Add(page);
            selectedMenuItems.Add(masterPageItem);
        }


    }
    private static bool IsToegevoegd(string title) {

        return prevPages.Last().ClassId == title;
    }
}
```

And this is the action that happens when you click on the action button(the navigation:

```cs
private void insertTaak_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var navPage = new DetailTaak("0") { Title = "Taak toevoegen" };

    var app = Application.Current as App;

    var mainPage = (MenuPage)app.MainPage;


    mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPageBar(navPage);
}
```

Comment: Try to find another event like `OnAppeared` or something equal which is fired each time the view is shown.

Comment: I can't find an eventhandler  for a button that is similar to onappeared.

Also can't seem to find a method to override with the same function as OnAppeared

Comment: "It doesn't enter when you press the backbutton." I can not reproduce this problem, how did you use this `FloatingActionButton`? How did you navigate to other page?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I've edited my post and included more information. I forgot to mention that I override my onbackbutton pressed ( u can see the method in my post). Do you think that method is the reason why it's failing?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens take a look at this person implementation https://github.com/keannan5390/Xamarin.Plugin.FAB/blob/master/Library/FloatingActionButton.Droid/FloatingActionButtonRenderer.cs

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the find, i'm trying to copy some things of him but most of it I will do tomorrow. I will tell you than if it worked or not. I was thinking to maybe just use his package but I can't find him in my package manager?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens nah I say look at how they did it and adapt it to what you want to do. Makes no sense grabbing everything if you only need a portion of the functionality. My main take away from what I saw i the code is that they do not just register on the size change event. I am thinking is you were to debug you code you would see that the element change events always happens but the size change probably doesn't. Put a break point and see.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, i'm going to look into that tomorrow, I want to thank you already! I was starting to give up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say forget about the size change event and try the update directly

```cs
public class FloatingActionButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
{
    private GradientDrawable _normal, _pressed;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var button = (FloatingActionButton)e.NewElement;
            this.UpdateStyle(button);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == FloatingActionButton.HeightProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == FloatingActionButton.WidthProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var button = (FloatingActionButton)sender;
            UpdateStyle(button);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateStyle(FloatingActionButton button)
    {
        try
        {
            var radius = (float)Math.Min(button.Width, button.Height) * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

            // Create a drawable for the button's normal state
            _normal = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();

            if (button.BackgroundColor.R == -1.0 && button.BackgroundColor.G == -1.0 && button.BackgroundColor.B == -1.0)
                _normal.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff2c2e2f"));
            else
                _normal.SetColor(button.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());

            _normal.SetCornerRadius(radius);

            // Create a drawable for the button's pressed state
            _pressed = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();
            var highlight = Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorActivatedHighlight }).GetColor(0, Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
            _pressed.SetColor(highlight);
            _pressed.SetCornerRadius(radius);

            // Add the drawables to a state list and assign the state list to the button
            var sld = new StateListDrawable();
            sld.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, _pressed);
            sld.AddState(new int[] { }, _normal);
            Control.SetBackground(sld);
        }
        catch
        {
            //...No-op
        }
    }
}
```